# Let $f$ be an analytic function. If $\Im(f) \Re(f) = 1$, prove that $f$ is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis

A function $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is everywhere differentiable, and $f(x+iy) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$, where $u,v$ are real-valued functions. Suppose that $u(x,y)v(x,y) = 1$ for all real $x,y$. Show that $f$ is constant.

I'm not sure how to approach this. This is what I tried.
Since $f$ is analytic, then the C-R equations hold:
$$u_x = v_y \ \ \ \ u_y = -v_x.$$

Also, using $uv = 1$, differentiating w.r.t $x$,
$$u_x v + v_x u = 0$$
and w.r.t $y$,
$$u_y v + v_y u = 0.$$
Hence, the C-R equations will simplify to
$$u_x = v_y = -\frac{u}{v}v_x$$
and
$$u_v = -v_x = \frac{u}{v}v_y$$
Not very sure what to do now.

Comment: What do you know about $f^2$? What are the real and imaginary parts of that?

Comment: Ahhh cool. Thanks. So $f^2$ is a constant, then $f$ must be a constant as well?

Comment: Since it is continuous and its domain is connected, yes, it must be constant. If $f^2$ is constant, then $f$ can attain at most two values. The continuity and connectedness of the domain of $f$ ensure that it can only attain one of these values.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Would you consider making that an answer? I'd like to upvote it, it's such a beautiful idea.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Already typing.

Comment: Curious -- were my steps going to lead anywhere?

Comment: Also, is there some theorem for the fact that "the continuity and connectedness of the domain of $f$ ensure that it can only attain one of these values"?

Comment: @Twenty-sixcolours With the right idea, yes, one can get to the end from your start. It's not even far, but one needs to see how to finish. Added that to my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to obtain the result is by looking at $f^2$. The assumption says $f^2$ has constant imaginary part, and that implies $f^2$ is constant (if that's not yet officially known, it's straightforward to deduce it from the Cauchy-Riemann equations). Say $f^2(z) \equiv c$. If $a^2 = c$, then $f(z) \in \{a, -a\}$ for all $z$, and by continuity both, $f^{-1}(a)$ and $f^{-1}(-a)$ are open. Since the domain of $f$ is connected, one of the two preimages must be empty, i.e. $f$ must be constant.

---

We can write the relations you found as

$$\begin{pmatrix} u_x & v_x \\ u_y & v_y \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} v \\ u\end{pmatrix} = 0.$$

Since $(u,v) \neq 0$, it follows that

$$0 = \det \begin{pmatrix} u_x & v_x \\ u_y & v_y \end{pmatrix} = u_x v_y - u_y v_x,$$

and by the Cauchy-Riemann equations, that determinant is $u_x^2 + u_y^2 = v_x^2 + v_y^2$. A sum of squares of real numbers is only zero if all the numbers are zero, so that implies $u_x = u_y = v_x = v_y = 0$, hence $f$ is constant.

Comment: It's not a Sony, it's a trick. =D